# Make the width 100% of textarea inside an xeditable using angularJS

Tags: css, angularjs, x-editable

In this example when the user want to edit the row or to add a new one, you can see the width of text-area(Description column) don't follow the width of the **td**, so I added some CSS, but no changes. So how can I make the width take the 100% of the **td** using CSS ?

This is the code :

```
      <span style="width:100%" editable-textarea="user.status" e-name="" e-form="rowform" e-ng-options="s.value as s.text for s in statuses">
           {{ showStatus(user) }}
      </span>
```

This is the **[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/659/)**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The span that you are adding `width: 100%` to actually gets hidden.  What you need to do is update the CSS for the class of the span that appears that wraps the inputs.  Seems to be `.editable-wrap`

http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/660/